# Firebase Storage C++ JNI jstring has wrong type:

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, firebase-storage

I am developing a Cocos2D-X game in which I've succesfully integrated firebase.

The problem I have is only on Android, on iOS it works fine.

This is the code:

```
    auto storage = firebase::storage::Storage::GetInstance(firebase::App::GetInstance());

    std::string stringPath = "users/" + currentId + "/image.png";
    auto child = storage->GetReference().Child(stringPath.c_str());

    //writtenPath is file:///data/user/0/app.game.Swipe/files/userImage.png
    auto future = child.PutFile(writtenPath.c_str());
```

And I get the following crash:

```
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jstring has wrong type: android.net.Uri$StringUri
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     in call to GetStringUTFChars
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from void com.google.firebase.app.internal.cpp.JniResultCallback.nativeOnResult(java.lang.Object, boolean, int, java.lang.String, long, long)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x750de730 self=0xf2105400
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | sysTid=14484 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf5730534
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=130 stm=25 core=1 HZ=100
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | stack=0xff60d000-0xff60f000 stackSize=8MB
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #00 pc 00350c69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+128)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #01 pc 0033117d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+304)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #02 pc 0023996f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+846)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #03 pc 00239ea7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+58)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #04 pc 000ca603  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+42)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #05 pc 000c9ebb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+566)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #06 pc 000c92a5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+184)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #07 pc 000c86d9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+800)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #08 pc 000ceebf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI22GetStringCharsInternalEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jstringPhbb+490)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #09 pc 000c4a51  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI17GetStringUTFCharsEP7_JNIEnvP8_jstringPh+24)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #10 pc 0069252d  /data/app/app.game.Swipe-2/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv17GetStringUTFCharsEP8_jstringPh+10)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #11 pc 00692d97  /data/app/app.game.Swipe-2/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN8firebase7storage8internal16MetadataInternal12download_urlEv+46)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #12 pc 00691abb  /data/app/app.game.Swipe-2/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZNK8firebase7storage8Metadata12download_urlEv+8)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #13 pc 00625ddc  /data/app/app.game.Swipe-2/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (???)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #14 pc 00625e94  /data/app/app.game.Swipe-2/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (???)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #15 pc 006a3f53  /data/app/app.game.Swipe-2/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN8firebase26ReferenceCountedFutureImpl26ReleaseMutexAndRunCallbackEj+70)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #16 pc 00695b97  /data/app/app.game.Swipe-2/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN8firebase7storage8internal24StorageReferenceInternal14FutureCallbackEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectbiPKcPv+1162)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #17 pc 0069f3c1  /data/app/app.game.Swipe-2/lib/arm/libMyGame.so (_ZN8firebase4util32JniResultCallback_nativeOnResultEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS4_hiP8_jstringxx+100)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #18 pc 00000ba9  /data/data/app.game.Swipe/code_cache/app_resources_lib.dex (Java_com_google_firebase_app_internal_cpp_JniResultCallback_nativeOnResult__Ljava_lang_Object_2ZILjava_lang_String_2JJ+172)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.google.firebase.app.internal.cpp.JniResultCallback.nativeOnResult(Native method)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.google.firebase.app.internal.cpp.JniResultCallback.onCompletion(JniResultCallback.java:196)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   - locked <0x0182127e> (a com.google.firebase.app.internal.cpp.JniResultCallback)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.google.firebase.app.internal.cpp.JniResultCallback$TaskCallback.onSuccess(JniResultCallback.java:106)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   - locked <0x017873df> (a java.lang.Object)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.google.firebase.storage.zzi.zzi(unavailable:-1)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.google.firebase.storage.zzz.run(unavailable:-1)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
    06-19 13:23:56.112 14484-14484/app.game.Swipe A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]
```

I also tried to remove the "file://" from the start of the string but then I got a file not found error.

Also I tried to do the same thing with the same file path (and image) and storage path but with Java code and it works without any errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

It seems like the crash occurs when I try to get the download url from the result data.

UPDATE 2:

I've spoken with the Firebase team and it seems like it's an internal problem. We've found a tideous workaround:

1. Get the download url with the dedicated method.
2. On the url you got to replace the / after the user with %2F

eg: ./users/-Kn-X3qD8QuP9C9jIPkx/image.png -> ./users%2F-Kn-X3qD8QuP9C9jIPkx%2Fimage.png

3. Parse the json you get and get from it the downloadTokens and modify the url so it looks like this:

./users%2F-Kn-X3qD8QuP9C9jIPkx%2Fimage.png?alt=media&token=downloadTokens

Comment: Have you checked on this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428379?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help me because i don't have access to the internal firebase code.